# MediaWiki template to fetch all the sections from a given {{PAGETITLE}} and display them in a markup ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediawiki, markup, wiki-markup

I am an admin user on a dedicated MediaWiki installation with no access to the server, therefore I can not install extensions.

I am trying to create a template called `{{DynamicPageSections|page_title}}` where, when used in any given page, it will generate a markup ordered list of all the sections contained in the specific page specified in `page_title`, with a result similar to this:

```
* [[page_title#section_1|#section_1]]
** [[page_title#section_1_1|#section_1]]
** [[page_title#section_1_2|#section_1_2]]
* [[page_title#section_2|#section_2]]
** [[page_title#section_2_1|#section_2_1]]
and so forth...
```

Where, of course, each item on the list is named just like the section on the desired page and links to the anchor of that specific section.

I realized i can create a dedicated JS library at `Wiki:my_js.js` and then import it using `importScript('MediaWiki:my_js.js');` added to the `MediaWiki:Common.js`.

I also figured out that I can use MediaWiki API to fetch all the sections in a given page in XML format using:
`'https://arcticsea.miraheze.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=parse&prop=sections&page=' + page_title;`

What I can't manage to do is how to convert the fetched XML into a well structured markup and then have it delivered to a separately constructed template.

I tried to write a separate function at the end of my_js.js like this:

```
function getSectionsFor(title){
    // the code for parsing the XML and rewriting it in MediaWiki markup
}

$(function () {
    var result = document.getElementById('dynamicSections');
    result.innerHTML = getSectionsFor('page_title');
}());
```

And then on my template I put:

```
<div id="dynamicSections"></div>
```

but no matter what I do in my principal `getSectionsFor(title)` function, I always get an empty string wherever I use the template.

Would appreciate help from anyone who is familiar with MediaWiki and the possibilities of executing dedicated JS for same source templating.

Comment: Could you please include your attempts in the question, even your code doesn't work? Also, the text you want to generate is written in wikitext, whereas you would need HTML if you were to insert a menu into the DOM.

Comment: It would probably be much easier to fetch the API information in JSON format. XML might look similar to HTML but their structure of the XML data does not relate to HTML at all.